Intermediate Value Theorem in Openstax Calculus book
I am looking at Openstax Calculus Volume 1. In the chapter on continuity, the statement of intermediate value theorem is given as follows
Let $f$ be continuous over a closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$. If $z$ is any real number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there is a number $c$ in $[a,b]$ satisfying $f(c) = z$
Now, in most of the Calculus books I have seen, number $c$ is in $(a,b)$ and not $[a,b]$. Are there two versions of this theorem ?
Thanks

If $z$ is strictly between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ then we can find $c \in (a,b)$. In this book they allow $z$ to be $f(a)$ or $f(b)$.

It says in the statement that $z$ is any number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Which means that either $f(a) < z < f(b)$ or $f(b) < z < f(a)$.

Is $z$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ inclusively ($f(a)\leq z\leq f(b)$) or exlcusively ($f(a)<z<f(b)$)? assume $f(a)\leq f(b)$

As indicated by the comment of math, the term between is ambiguous.  Often, when a mathematician uses that term, they will explicitly specify between...inclusive or between...exclusive.

So, author should have been more careful here I guess. Since this is an open book in Calculus, authors should have used more rigorous definition. This is leading to confusion

As prior comments note, what is asserted depends on whether between means strict or non-strict inequality. On the other hand, it's a good (edifying, and not difficult) exercise to formulate two precise statements for continuous, real-valued functions $f$ on $[a, b]$, one for strict inequality and one for non-strict, and to show these statements are logically equivalent (each implies the other). The end result is, "No, there are not two versions of the intermediate value theorem (in the sense asked)." ;)

Whether $c\in(a,b)$ or $c\in[a,b]$ depends on the stricit and non-strict inequality
